# Defaulting a section in a Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here's the situation I'm trying to solve:

I have a main shared layout with a single section @RenderSection("Menu") that I want to default to a standard menu for the majority of my pages, but I would like to replace/override that section in a few sub pages. Is this possible with Razor at this stage in the game?

I was hoping I could possibly define the default implementation of that section in _ViewStart.cshtml but it doesn't seem to like it.

Would a Menu Partial view be better for this situation?

Edit:

I'm getting the following error with this code now: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "menu".

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
            <div id="menu">
@if (IsSectionDefined("menu"))
{
    RenderSection("menu");
}
else { 
    <text>
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li><a href="#">Lookups</a>
                    <ul>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Product","Index","Product")
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </text>
}
        </div>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@section menu {
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product", "Index", "Product")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Form Type", "Index", "Product")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Supplier", "Index", "Product")</li>
            </ul>
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ah... I was messing with this and found I could do it by just switching the logic around:

```
@RenderSection("Header", false)
@if (!IsSectionDefined("Header")) { 
<header>
    Default Header!
</header>
}
```

So if my pages don't define `@section Header { ... }`, it renders the default.

Comment: Thanks Andy. That worked well for me and I think it's a little cleaner than the separate menu partial.

Answer (score 21):

The `IsSectionDefined` method should suite your needs:

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("Menu")) {
    @RenderSection("Menu")
} else {
    <text>
        Default Menu Content.
    </text>
}
```

**Update**: I wrote a blog post to better illustrate the available options: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/marcinon/Optional-Razor-Sections-with-Default-Content)

Comment: Thanks, I've given it a go but I'm getting: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "menu". I'll add my code to my OP to show what I've done.

Comment: I updated the code to fix the issue. You need to do `@RenderSection()` instead of just `RenderSection()`

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using multiple layouts to achieve this exact same scenario.

**/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <div id="menu">@RenderSection("Menu", required:false)</div>
    ...
    @RenderBody()
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

**/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithDefaultMenu.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
@section Menu { @Html.Partial("Menu") }
@RenderBody()
```

**/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithDefaultMenu.cshtml"; }
```

What this means is that, by default, all of my views get the layout with a default menu. However, on a view-by-view basis, I can set the Layout to `_Layout.cshtml` and then implement `@section Menu` myself.

Comment: I tried both approaches and although I think the other approach is cleaner, yours worked while in the other I'm getting the error I mentioned above in the edit.